# itunes required from frustrated Apple fan

Tags: windows-7, itunes, ssd

iTunes saves the backup files in `/Users/username/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup`. Can i move this folder elsewhere? I have 14+ Terabytes of storage and a 60GB SSD 'c' drive that iTunes has filled up. I can't update or backup my devices (3 of them) even if i remove the old  backup.
Any thoughts / ideas?

Comment: Maybe it's enough to delete some old backups? Go to iTunes->Settings->Devices. It's also fine to remove old backups here and paste them back later if you need them - iTunes will be able to restore them.

Comment: Are you using Mac OS X (the path) or Windows (question tag)?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: move the backup, then symlink (*mklink* in Windows) to the new location.

Step by step: http://aaltonen.us/2011/01/03/change-the-location-of-your-iphone-backup/

Comment: thanks - seems like a waste of time as you have to copy twice... kind of computing you'd have expected 15 years ago...? :)

Comment: Copy *twice*? Where'd you get that from?

Comment: Just in case I appreciate your feedback and the advice...I was referring to the necessity to have to do this as it's such as obvious flaw from Apple.

Comment: @steve I thought Apple hasn't sold SSDs that small for a few years? What model Mac are you using?